# Como criar uma nova coluna 'ANO_NASCIMENTO' e inserir dados a ela de forma sequenciada, considerando cada linha da coluna NOME

Tags: python, funções, data

Olá!! Sou iniciante no *Python* e gostaria de contar com o ajuda de vocês para os problemas abaixo.

Tenho um *df* com 2 colunas.

> ```
> NOME                      N.CELULAR           
> João Pedro                98 – 9112 1632
> Luís Antônio              98 – 8513 4545
> Renato gome               98 – 9002 4012
> Selma lira                98– 8807 1943
> Luiza ving                98 – 8125 1448
> Paulo junior              98 – 9056 1435
> Manoel mendonça           98 – 9115 1616
> ```

Preciso criar uma terceira coluna de nome `ANO_NASCIMENTO` e inserir/adicionar dados a ela de forma sequenciada, considerando cada linha da coluna `NOME`. Acredito que esteja longe do que quero, mas tentei a função `append`. O fato é que não tenho certeza de como fazer isso.

```
df["ANO_NASC"] = ' '
ANO_NASC = [ ]
Ano_nasc = int(input('Qual o ano de seu Nascimento?'))
if Ano_nasc > 0:
    ANO_NASC.append(Ano_nasc)
else:
    print('Fim')
```

Qualquer ajuda será bem vinda.

Comment: Você está usando alguma library ou só o Python puro? Se for o segundo caso, você pode transformar a segunda coluna em uma lista, e deixar só os telefones na primeira! Assim, o número de cada pessoa serve pra identificar ela.

Comment: Estou usando  pandas

Comment: Então eu não tenho experiência pra te ajudar. Perdão.

Comment: De todo modo, agradeço a tentativa.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você tem duas opções, inserir diretamente na coluna ou criar uma lista e depois adicionar os valores de uma vez. Seguem os detalhes.

## Código base:

```
import pandas as pd

dados = [
    {"NOME": "João Pedro", "N.CELULAR": "98 – 9112 1632"},
    {"NOME": "Luís Antônio", "N.CELULAR": "98 – 8513 4545"},
    {"NOME": "Renato gome", "N.CELULAR": "98 – 9002 4012"},
    {"NOME": "Selma lira", "N.CELULAR": "98 – 8807 1943"},
    {"NOME": "Luiza ving", "N.CELULAR": "98 – 8125 1448"},
    {"NOME": "Paulo junior", "N.CELULAR": "98 – 9056 1435"},
    {"NOME": "Manoel mendonça", "N.CELULAR": "98 – 9115 1616"}
]

df = pd.DataFrame(dados)
```

## Opção 1 - Inserir diretamente na coluna:

```
df['ANO_NASCIMENTO_Opcao_1'] = ""
for index, nome in enumerate(df['NOME']):
    texto = f'{nome}, qual o ano de seu Nascimento? '
    data = int(input(texto))
    df['ANO_NASCIMENTO_Opcao_1'].iat[index] = data
```

## Opção 2 - Inserir valores depois de obtidos:

```
datas = list()
for nome in df['NOME']:
    texto = f'{nome}, qual o ano de seu Nascimento? '
    data = int(input(texto))
    datas.append(data)

df['ANO_NASCIMENTO_Opcao_2'] = datas
```

## Imprimir dataframe

```
print(df)
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Olá!! Suas respostas são boas e atendem a solicitação, consegui avança.